# jquery draggable, droppable and edittable function

Tags: jquery, draggable, droppable

I am looking to create a text box that has editor elements (bold, italics, underline, hyperlink). I want this box to be draggable and droppable. Can anyone point me to a demo/code so i can figure out how to do this?

Comment: Are you wanting the editor components to be drag/drop or the text box as well?

Comment: Try http://jsfiddle.net/AqTFQ/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [Tinymce](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php) inside some div and enable the div with jquery UI dragdrop effects

An example here http://jsfiddle.net/AqTFQ/